# Does drinking water increase the risk of shock with an open wound?

Tags: first-aid, hydration, bleeding

First let me explain the scenario:
Someone received an open wound, lets assume from a cut so no blunt-forced trauma meaning no reason to suspect internal injuries. The wound is bad enough that serious blood loss occurs. This happens in a remote place, so medevac and professional health care, are if at all available, delayed by days. A good first aid kit is available, but nothing like IVs. Initial wound care has been done (this is not the part I am interested in here, assume it has been done correctly).

Obviously the patient will need hydration. The question is whether hydration should be delayed or not?
Broken down: Does drinking water have any detrimental effect in terms of stopping the bleeding and chances to get into a state of shock?

Typical unspecific first aid recommendations state to not give a patient anything to drink. If a reason is given for this, it is usually that the patient might need surgery. This is not an issue in this case. Also with food it is clear that it is a bad idea, as digestion "needs blood", same for water? There is a (seemingly dubious) [discussion on Nairaland Forum](http://www.nairaland.com/1460146/dont-drink-water-bleeding-injury) where someone states that it will "only dilute the blood" and it is again more directed at internal injuries. And AFAIK it is a normal procedure to give a trauma victim fluids over IV before blood transfusions are available, so this seems wrong to me.

Comment: The only reason to withhold water from an injured person is because they may not be fully conscious, or may lose consciousness, and the water presents a choking and/or vomiting risk. But if they are fully conscious then they need water even more than an uninjured person does. They have, after all, suffered a significant loss of blood, which is mostly water and that needs to be replaced. The person who said it will dilute their blood is utterly clueless.